# How to use a dll without knowing parameters?

Tags: windows, dll

I have a dll that I need to make use of. I also have a program that makes calls to this dll to use it. I need to be able to use this dll in another program, however previous programmer did not leave any documentation or source code. Is there a way I can monitor what calls are made to this dll and what is passed?

Comment: What language was it in, any clue?

Comment: client doesnt know, but using DependencyWalker it looks like either c or c++ style function names.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, in general. This is from the [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) FAQ:

> Q:    How do I view the parameter and
>   return types of a function?
>
> A:    For most functions, this
>   information is simply not present in
>   the module. The Windows' module file
>   format only provides a single text
>   string to identify each function.
>   There is no structured way to list the
>   number of parameters, the parameter
>   types, or the return type. However,
>   some languages do something called
>   function "decoration" or "mangling",
>   which is the process of encoding
>   information into the text string. For
>   example, a function like int Foo(int,
>   int) encoded with simple decoration
>   might be exported as _Foo@8. The 8
>   refers to the number of bytes used by
>   the parameters. If C++ decoration is
>   used, the function would be exported
>   as ?Foo@@YGHHH@Z, which can be
>   directly decoded back to the
>   function's original prototype: int
>   Foo(int, int). Dependency Walker
>   supports C++ undecoration by using the
>   Undecorate C++ Functions Command.

**Edit:** One thing you could do, I think, is to get a disassembler and disassemble the DLL and/or the calling code, and work out from that the number and types of the arguments, and the return types. You wouldn't be able to find out the names of the arguments though.

Answer (score 1):

You can *[hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/hooks.aspx)* the functions in the DLL you wish to monitor (if you know how many arguments they take)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dumpbin` (Which is part of the Visual Studio Professional or VC++ Express, or download the platform kit, or even use [OpenWatcom](http://openwatcom.org) C++) on the DLL to look for the 'exports' section, as an example:

```
dumpbin /all SimpleLib.dll | more

Output would be:
  Section contains the following exports for SimpleLib.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    4A15B11F time date stamp Thu May 21 20:53:03 2009
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           2 number of functions
           2 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001010 fnSimpleLib
          2    1 00001030 fnSimpleLib2
```

Look at the ordinals, there are the two functions exported...the only thing is to work out what parameters are used...

You can also use the [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com) to find this out for you. Working out the parameters is a bit tricky, you would need to disassemble the binary, and look for the function call at the offset in the file, then work out the parameters by looking at the 'SP', 'BP' registers.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.